# Page Layout for Categories using XML

Tags: module, layout, magento-1, xml, layout-update

I want to have a specific layout for some of my category pages but instead of always using the XML Layout Update

```
<reference name="right">
<remove name="left.reports.product.viewed"/>
<remove name="newsletter"/>
</reference>
```

and so on....

Like this I would prefer to have my normal 3 page column layout and have this for specific categories as a Page Layout. 
So that instead of copying and pasting the code I could just pick
LAYOUT A from the dropdown and this removing of the blocks would be done for me.

I thought I could create a somehting [like this](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-cms-page-layout/) but then my page wouldn´t load any css and it would also not remove the blocks as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all my pages I did it this way

Catalog.xml (so its on the product pages)

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
             <reference name="content">
<block type="cms/block" name="sale_banner" as="sale_banner" before="product.info"><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>sale_banner</block_id></action></block>...
```

In the page.xml

```
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
<block type="cms/block" name="sale_banner" as="sale_banner" before="feature_titles"><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>sale_banner</block_id></action></block>
```

Where "feature_titles" is a block on every page at the top. And then in the according .phtml file

```
<div class="col-main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sale_banner') ?>
```

In the main div i call the childhtml and then I create a static block in the Magento backend using the "sale_banner" as Identifier